# JavaScript library or code to track user clicks to generate heatmaps

Tags: javascript, heatmap

Is there any JS library or code available to track user clicks? We'll use this to generate heatmaps using Heatmap.js.

This JS lib/code is supposed to work with **fixed and liquid CSS layouts, cross browser,  and different screen resolutions**.

We have tried some simple tracking code, but it's not tracking the click positions properly for different screen resolutions and layouts.

I just wanted to check if something like this already has been implemented so that we can avoid reinventing the wheel and save time.

Any help, links, suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is definitely something that should be googled, not asked on SO.

Comment: Sean, I've spent a good amount of time googling this but couldn't get a specific solution. I posted here with a hope that someone may already have came across with this situation and could guide better.

Comment: I would hack heatmap.js to your needs. Otherwise write your own or use http://code.google.com/p/mapchen-heatmap/

Comment: Larry, do you mean `hack heatmap.js` for click tracking part? Thanks for the mapchen-heatmap link.

Answer (score 0):

I found this website today searching for the same thing : www.crazyegg.com however I think you should "buy" their services instead of just importing a .js .